# TextBoxes not synchronized after introducing CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having trouble with some TextBoxes which are to be synchronized with the current element selected in a ListBox. E.g. I have the following TextBoxes:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource IdTextboxStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextboxStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=CodeName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I also have the following ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="ListOfAgentsBox" Margin="20, 5, 5, 5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AgentsViewSource}}" 
      SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=CurrentIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Which contains the current elements in a collection named Agents, which is a collection of Agent elements.

My problem is, before introducing the following CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="AgentsViewSource"
                          Source="{StaticResource Agents}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="ID" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Everything seemed to work fine - I could click the different elements in the ListBox and edit them just fine in the TextBoxes. However, the TextBoxes and the ListBox are no longer syncrhonized, and I have no idea why.

Comment: `CodeName` points to name of selected item in listBox? Post code for that as well.

Comment: you may perhaps use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedIndex`, see if that helps.